# Partial Dependency plots and Gradient boosting (GBM package)

Tags: r, boosting

Is it possible to plot a partial dependency plot to display the class probability and estimate the effects of a predictor for a [GBM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf) model? 
Something similar to `partialPlot` from `randomForest` package.

[image]

According to this [article](http://adventuresindm.blogspot.gr/2013/01/partial-dependency-plots-and-gbm.html), a partial plot is doable with gbm.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's really easy. Check out `?plot.gbm`. The usage goes like this:

```
 plot(gbm.model, i.var = 1, lwd = 2, col = "blue", main = "")
```

and looks like
[image]

`i.var` controls the index of the variable to plot. You can also do two (or more) way plots using

```
 plot(gbm.model, i.var = c(1,2), lwd = 2, col = "blue", main = "")
```

Comment: thank you, i really appreciate your efforts and time here and in your blog.